# How to access Custom Form data within the AtTask REST API (version 4+)?

Tags: api, rest, attask

For a project I'm working on, I need to access Custom Form data via the AtTask REST API. Specifically, I need to surface the text associated with any checked checkboxes within a custom form.

To see where this data might be visible, I've done a query of the form:

```
https://<company>.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v4.0/task/search?method=get&sessionID=xxxxxxxx&fields=parameterValues
```

...but I'm not seeing the checkbox data I'm looking for.

Is it possible to surface this kind of data via the API?

If so, what's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterValues fields will return all the custom data that is set on the task.  You can request the specific parameter by calling it by name like DE:Parameter Name.  Both will only return the selected values of the checkbox.  If you would like all values for the field then you will need to pull them from the parameter and parameter options objects.

```
https://<company>.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/popt/metadata
```